# image preprocessing tesseract

Tags: opencv, preprocessor, ocr, tesseract

I'm doing a business card scanner for my final examination about digital image processing, and I would ask to you how I have to preprocess a photo of a business card so tesseract can recognize text. I tried a lot of things, like erosion, dilation, thresholding, but I can't have a good result... Can you help me?

Thank you

Marco

Comment: Provide some images to show how is your acquisition quality.

Answer (score 2):

If your concern is only about text recognition and not about preprocessing, consider using [ScanTailor](http://scantailor.sourceforge.net/). It is an excellent pre-processing tool and it is open source.

If you want to implement the pre-processing yourself, you might want to have a look at [this paper](http://www.vincent-net.com/luc/papers/10wiley_morpho_DIAapps.pdf) - especially the skew correction and the background estimation.The results of the algorithms described here are good. ScanTailor uses some of these.

Comment: this is great info! I've been struggling with preprocessing and your answer is the first I've heard of ScanTailor. Are there any similar tools that are non-interactive ?

Comment: @Ivar There is one other free tool - ocropus which offers command line interfaces. From my experience, a fully automatic approach never works except when your input images are almost spotlessly accurate.I also remember a paid tool Abby fine reader - but I have not worked with it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the open source C++  image processing library OpenCV combination with the open source free Optical Character Recognition (OCR) library tesseract. 
Since your information of your problem isn't quite specific, i can answer your question in general
The main procedure in OCR is:

1. perform some kind of preprocessing on the image
2. text detection to get your ROI (Region of interest, the region containing your text)
3. character detection (take the text-only image and use it as input for tesseract

a few words about tesseract:
There is a lot of information to the library available online. It is a google open source library used for the google books OCR purpose. Can also handle layout analyzes in your image, but isn't perfect in this, therefore a preprocessing yourself and using tesseract only for the real character recognition part can lead to a better result. Feel free to question, if you still have questions, or if I missunderstood your question.